# How to delete duplicates and original values if the duplicates are located in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeking guidance on how to create a macro that can delete duplicate and original values if the duplicates are located in another worksheet. Here is an example of the workbook:

```
Sheet1
Class People
cs101 12
cs102 13
cs102 13

Sheet2
People Class
12     cs101
15     cs105

Sheet3
Room People Class
key1 12     cs101
key2 16     cs106
```

In this dataset, I want to remove rows that have "cs101" in all 3 worksheets, but I don't want to remove "cs102" since the duplicate is listed on the same worksheet.

The code below will help me on deleting duplicates and original values across multiple worksheets, but it will remove "cs102" row as well. Any guidance is appreciated, thank you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDupes()

Const wsNamesList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
Const HeaderTitle As String = "Class"
Const HeaderRow As Long = 1

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(wsNames)

Dim cRanges() As Range: ReDim cRanges(0 To nUpper)
Dim cData() As Variant: ReDim cData(0 To nUpper)

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' A = a

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim crg As Range
Dim hCell As Range
Dim n As Long

For n = 0 To nUpper
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the worksheet ('ws').
    Set ws = RefWorksheet(wb, wsNames(n))
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ' Attempt to create a reference to the header cell ('hCell').
        Set hCell = RefHeader(ws, HeaderTitle, HeaderRow)
        If Not hCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Attempt to create a reference to the range ('crg').
            Set crg = RefColumnRange(hCell.Offset(1))
            If Not crg Is Nothing Then
                ' Store the range in an array ('cRanges').
                Set cRanges(n) = crg
                ' Write the values from the ranges to an array ('cData').
                cData(n) = GetColumnRange(crg)
                ' Write and count the unqiue values from the array
                ' to a dictionary ('dict').
                FirstColumnToDictionaryWithCount dict, cData(n)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next n
                
Dim drg() As Range: ReDim drg(0 To nUpper)
Dim r As Long

' Combine all cells containing duplicates (and the originals)
' into one range ('drg()') per worksheet.
For n = 0 To nUpper
    If Not cRanges(n) Is Nothing Then
        For r = 1 To UBound(cData(n), 1)
            If dict(cData(n)(r, 1)) > 1 Then
                Set drg(n) = GetCombinedRange(drg(n), cRanges(n).Cells(r))
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next n
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Delete the entire rows of the ranges in one go per worksheet.
For n = 0 To nUpper
    If Not drg(n) Is Nothing Then
        drg(n).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next n
                
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a workbook ('wb'), creates a reference to the worksheet
'               named after a value ('WorksheetName').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefWorksheet( _
ByVal wb As Workbook, _
ByVal WorksheetName As String) _
As Worksheet
If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function

On Error Resume Next
Set RefWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
On Error GoTo 0

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a worksheet's ('ws') row ('HeaderRow'), creates a reference
'               to the cell containing a value ('Title').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefHeader( _
ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
ByVal Title As String, _
Optional ByVal HeaderRow As Long = 1) _
As Range
If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function
If HeaderRow < 1 Then Exit Function
If HeaderRow > ws.Rows.Count Then Exit Function

Dim hCell As Range
With ws.Rows(HeaderRow)
    Set hCell = .Find(Title, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
End With
If hCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function

Set RefHeader = hCell
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a one-column range from a cell
'               ('FirstCellRange') to the bottom-most non-empty cell.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumnRange( _
ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
If FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

Dim lCell As Range
With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
    Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Set RefColumnRange = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a one-column range ('ColumnRange')
'               in a 2D one-based one-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnRange( _
ByVal ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant
If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

Dim rCount As Long: rCount = ColumnRange.Rows.Count

Dim cData As Variant

With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = .Value
    Else
        cData = .Value
    End If
End With

GetColumnRange = cData
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Appends the unique values and their count of the first column
'               of a 2D one-based array ('cData') to a dictionary ('dict').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub FirstColumnToDictionaryWithCount( _
    ByRef dict As Object, _
    ByVal cData As Variant)
If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(cData) Then Exit Sub

Dim cValue As Variant
Dim r As Long

For r = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
    cValue = cData(r, 1)
    If Not IsError(cValue) Then
        If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
            dict(cValue) = dict(cValue) + 1
        End If
    End If
Next r

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Combines two ranges into one range.
'               Note that the ranges have to be located in the same worksheet.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetCombinedRange( _
ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range

If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
    Set GetCombinedRange = AddRange
Else
    Set GetCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all due respect to those who would employ dictionaries and classes, I think this can be resolved with more pedestrian methods. The code below applies the logic that if a "Class ID" from Sheet1 is found in either Sheet2 or Sheet3 (or both) it should be deleted there and in Sheet1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    ' 291
    
    ' change the tab names to match actual names
    ' use Chr(124) vertical bar as separator
    Const TabNames  As String = "Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3"
    ' "Class" is in column A on Sheet1, column B on Sheet2 and column C on Sheet3
    Const ClassClm  As String = "A,B,C"
    Const FirstRow  As Long = 2             ' same on all sheets

    Dim Ws()        As Worksheet
    Dim Clm()       As Long                 ' columns in which "Class" is found
    Dim Rng()       As Range                ' used ranges in Ws()
    Dim Idx         As Integer              ' index of Ws(), Rng() and Clm()
    Dim Fnd         As Range                ' found duplicate's cell
    Dim Del         As Boolean              ' deletopn tok place
    Dim Tmp         As Variant              ' helper
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter: rows of Ws(1)
    
    Tmp = Split(TabNames, "|")
    ReDim Ws(1 To UBound(Tmp) + 1)
    ReDim Clm(1 To UBound(Tmp) + 1)
    ReDim Rng(1 To UBound(Tmp) + 1)
    For Idx = 1 To UBound(Ws)
        Set Ws(Idx) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Tmp(Idx - 1))
        Clm(Idx) = Columns(Split(ClassClm, ",")(Idx - 1)).Column
    Next Idx
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    SetSheetRanges Rng, Ws, Clm
    For R = Rng(1).Rows.Count To FirstRow Step -1
        For Idx = 2 To UBound(Ws)
            Set Fnd = Rng(Idx).Find(Rng(1).Cells(R).Value, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                With Fnd
                    .Worksheet.Rows(.Row).Delete
                End With
                SetSheetRanges Rng, Ws, Clm, Idx
                Del = True
            End If
        Next Idx
        
        If Del Then
            Ws(1).Rows(R).Delete
            SetSheetRanges Rng, Ws, Clm, 1
            Del = False
        End If
    Next R
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SetSheetRanges(Fun() As Range, _
                           Ws() As Worksheet, _
                           Clm() As Long, _
                           Optional ByVal Idx As Integer)
    ' 291
    
    Dim i           As Integer              ' index of Ws()
    Dim Rl          As Long
    
    For i = LBound(Ws) To UBound(Ws)
        If (i = Idx) Or (Idx = 0) Then
            With Ws(i)
                Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Clm(i)).End(xlUp).Row
                Set Fun(i) = .Range(.Cells(1, Clm(i)), .Cells(Rl, Clm(i)))
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! What if I have 6 sheets and I have "Class" as column A in sheet4? I'm still a beginner on VBA and I appreciate any explanation on this question.

Comment: No disrespect taken! I'm just a tinkerer. Follow up question (no contention, I only hope to learn more), what's the advantage of avoiding dictionaries and classes?

Comment: So long as they all produce the same result, differences are in speed and maintenance cost. I think your data size is so small that speed doesn't matter. They are all fast enough. Therefore the advantage is with the code that you find easiest to understand and therefore most likely to be able to modify within the shortest time when needed.

Comment: I don't think I understand your earlier question. My code allows you to specify any number of sheets in the constant  `TabNames` and set a different column for "Class" for each in the constant `ClassClm`. But this isn't a question about VBA. It's about how to use/customize the procedure I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

How about a dictionary of class ID's whose values are the number of sheets on which the class exists, and another dictionary that tests if the class has already been counted for any worksheet? Something like:

```
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim oClassRange As Range
Dim oClass As Range
Dim oClasses As Object: Set oClasses = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim oWSClass As Object
For Each oWS in ThisWorkbook
    'start with a blank dictionary for each worksheet
    Set oWSClass = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set oClassRange = {define the range with class ID's}
    For Each oClass In oClassRange
        sID = oClass.Value2
        If Not oWSClass.Exists(sID) Then 'only add or increment if it's the first time class appears on this worksheet
            oWSClass.Add sID, 1
            If oClasses.Exists(sID) Then oClasses(sID) = oClasses(sID) + 1 _
                Else oClasses.Add sID, 1
        End If
    Next oClassRange
Next oWS
```

Then iterate the `oClasses` dictionary entries, and any value of 3 triggers deleting the rows from each worksheet.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it out, but since I'm only a tinkerer, I'm not sure if it's proper technique, but `oClasses(sID) = oClasses(sID) + 1`  adds the key and sets its value to "1" if the key doesn't exist, so you could simplify that "IF" statement